# Where to find the data to compare the decentralisation of mining for different cryptos?

Tags: mining-pools, block, nodes, decentralization

I'd like to compare the centralisation of BTC's mining / nodes / pools for BTC and other alts. Where can data be found on this?

Thank you!

David

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is data on [bitcoin mining distribution](https://blockchain.info/pools) and [ethereum mining distribution](https://etherscan.io/stat/miner?range=1&blocktype=blocks)